# pg_restore throws warnings and return exit 1

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restore a PostgreSQL database using the command below:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -d databaseName Backup.dump
```

The restoring is done successfully. But it displays below warning message in the end.

```
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 97
```

Due to which my shell script is failing as the command returns exit 1 code.

Can anyone please guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by dropping the database, creating it and then storing a clean database.